# Prove $e^{-ax} \le (1-x)^a + \frac{1}{2}ax^2$ for $a > 1$ and $0 \le x \le 1$:

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponentiation

Prove that for all $a > 1$ and $0 \le x \le 1$:

$$
  e^{-ax} \le (1-x)^a + \frac{1}{2}ax^2
$$

My very limited start:

$f(x) = (1-x)^a + \frac{1}{2}ax^2 - e^{-ax} \ge 0$

$f'(x) = ax + a e^{-ax} - a(1-x)^{a-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note from the well known $e^{t} \geqslant 1+t$ that
$$e^{-ax} \geqslant (1-x)^a = (1-x)^{a-1}- x(1-x)^{a-1} \geqslant (1-x)^{a-1}-x$$

Multiply by $-a$ to get
$$-a e^{-ax} \leqslant -a(1-x)^{a-1} + ax$$

Integrating this in $[0, x]$ gives
$$e^{-ax}\color{red}{-1} \leqslant (1-x)^a\color{red}{-1} + \frac12ax^2$$

Comment: How do you go from $e^t\ge1+t$ to $e^{-ax}\ge(1-x)^a$? Note that $(1-x)^a \ge (1-ax)$ for $a>1$.

Comment: First replace $t \to -x$.  Then raise both sides to the positive power $a$.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Thanks! +1

Comment: How do you do the next step to go from $(1-x)^a$ to $(1-x)^{a-1} - x (1-x)^{a-1}$?

Comment: @clay $(1-x)^a=(1-x)(1-x)^{a-1}=...$ work it out...

Comment: @Macavity, wow. sorry about that. I wasn't thinking.